# Are loaded OpenGL functions context- or thread- specific? (Windows)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, opengl

Consider a scenario where 2 rendering contexts (each belonging to their own distinct window) exist in 2 separate threads of execution. Do OpenGL function pointers need to be loaded and used separately for each of them? Or can the gl* function pointers be global, loaded only once for a given application instance and used by both windows or contexts?

The reason I am asking is because the [OpenGL Function Loading Docs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions), when talking about loading wgl functions, states:

> This function only works in the presence of a valid OpenGL context. **Indeed, the function pointers it returns are themselves context-specific**. The Windows documentation for this function states that the functions returned may work with another context, depending on the vendor of that context and that context's pixel format.
>
> In practice, if two contexts come from the same vendor and refer to the same GPU, then the function pointers pulled from one context will work in the other. This is important when creating an OpenGL context in Windows, as you need to create a "dummy" context to get WGL extension functions to create the real one.

emphasis mine.

I was wondering if such a requirement also existed for the OpenGL functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed one sentence before the paragraph you copied in your question (emphasis is mine):

> [...] **The functions can be OpenGL functions or platform-specific WGL functions**.
>
> This function only works in the presence of a valid OpenGL context. Indeed, the function pointers it returns are themselves context-specific [...]

This means loaded OpenGL functions are context-specific like WGL functions are on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Old hardware may return different function pointers for different contexts. Nowadays I doubt it. GLEW is moving to avoid this multi-context (MX) feature.